# C++ message encoder using an array of structures

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I have written a program to read in two columns of letters from a text file and use those letters to encode and decode a message entered from the keyboard. I have the program compiling, however it just gives me weird white bars instead of an encoded message. I think I have the void functions written correctly, however I am a little confused on how to read in each character at a time from the users inputed message. I will give you the code and compete instructions below:

Use an array of structures to code and decode messages.  The structure will have two elements: an input character and an output character. Using this array your program will encode and decode messages.

Your program should have the following functions:

```
loadArray - this function will read a file containing 26 character pairs.  These pairs will be loaded into an array of 26 rows.  The first value of the pair is the input character and the second is the output character.
encode - this function will take 2 parameters, the array and a single character.  It will return the output character associated with the parameter character.  If no match is found the original character is returned.
decode - this function will be the inverse of the encode function and will match the character parameter with the output character in the array and return the input character, or the original character if no match is found
```

In the main function, after loading the array, the program will prompt the user for a message string. It will then encode the message by calling the encode function for each character in the message and replacing it with the encoded value.

To verify your results, use the encoded message and decode it to ensure that you get back the original message.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<array>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
struct code
{
    char input;
    char output;
};



void loadArray(code[]);
void encode(code[], char);
void decode(code[], char);

int main()
{
    code input[26];
    string message;
    char output;


    loadArray;

    // prompt the user for the message
    cout << "Enter your message" << endl;
    cin >> message;


    for (char& c : message) {
        encode(input, c);
    }



    return 0;
}


void loadArray(code c[])
{
    ifstream in("codeFile.txt");

    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++){
        in >> c[i].input >> c[i].output;

    }


    }

void encode(code c[], char in)
{
    int encMessage;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 26; i++){
        if (c[i].input == in){
            cout << c[i].output;
            }
    }
}

void decode(code c[], char out)
{
    int decMessage;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 26; i++){
        if (c[i].output == out){
            cout << c[i].input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (c[i].input = in)` Most likely, you mean `if (c[i].input == in)` Consult your favorite C++ textbook about a difference between assignment and equality comparison operators.

Comment: totally missed that typo haha. Thanks, however it still wont output the encoded message. I had thought if I did cout << c[ i ].input; it would out put the message when the function was called. Am i wrong on this?

Comment: I don't see `output` ever being assigned a value (nor `input`, for that matter). You are printing random garbage. Did you mean to call `loadArray` at some point?

Comment: I am not printing anything at this point, I added the load array, but I am spacing on how to call the input function. I lost all of my previous projects and files so have nothing for reference. The book I have is worthless i have read it through and through plus it does not cover arrays of structures. I did not assign the output function a value yet because i need the input function to work first.

Comment: "I am not printing anything at this point" I could have sworn I saw `cout << c[i].output;` line in your code.

Comment: `loadArray;` This doesn't call a function - in fact, it does exactly nothing.

Comment: The program wont print anything with the code that I am showing you. That is the whole problem I am having.

Comment: False - it does print something, but that something is random garbage stored in uninitialized variables. That's what your "weird white bars" are.

Comment: It works now. I just did not load the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to go further :

- you try to call `loadArray` as `loadArray;` - in C++ you need parentheses to call function : it should be `loadArray(input);`
- your functions encode and decode are `void`. That's wrong. They should return the encoded (resp decoded) char, first per requirement (*It will return ...*), next to build the encoded string

Comment: `loadArray()` won't compile - the function is declared to take a parameter.